# Why does this RewriteRule in httpd not work?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd, query

I tried to set this RewriteCond in httpd 2.4.4:

```
...
RewriteCond expr "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /welcome/"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1\.html
```

So, if I visit `https://localhost/?welcome` , for example, I should see the page `https://localhost/welcome.html`.

Instead, it returns a 500 Internal Server Error. Why?

The error log reads:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: On HTTP 500 there should be something in your error.log

Comment: @PascalSchmiel Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (welcome)
RewriteRule ^.*$ %1.html
```

This replaces the %1 with the matching group from the RewriteCond. Because you are using here a static string you can just use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  welcome
RewriteRule ^.*$ welcome.html
```

Comment: I understand, but it redirects me on  /.html not /welcome.html. Why is that?

Comment: tried this on my own and edited my answer.

Comment: and if I use a dynamic string?

Comment: Then you can use the expression you want in your RewriteCond, put it in brackets an reference to it using %1 - exactly like in the first example - but use some expression instead of "welcome"

Comment: Yes, but i meant concatenate the %1 and some other string, such as %1pageoftoday . How could i do?

Comment: exactly as you did it in your comment :) - %1pageoftheday.html - or whatever

Comment: but it doesn't work anyway. I tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1` for get welcome.html when the query contains "welcome" . It returns `You don't have permission to access /.html on this server.`

Comment: Don't mix up $1 and %1 - $1 refers to the brackets from your RewriteRule. What you want is the content from the brackets from your RewriteCond - that is %1

Comment: oh,excuse-me i wrote %1 , but here i reported badly. Anyway it doesn't work.

Comment: excuse-me, this is the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.html
`

Comment: how does your current ruleset looks like and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i always get `You don't have permission to access /.html on this server`

Comment: Then: `RewriteCond expr "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /welcome/"
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.html`

Comment: I want that when i type `https://localhost/?welcome` it returns `https://localhost/welcome.html`, but in a dynamic way, not by writing in the rewriterule directly `welcome.html`

Comment: you have to put "welcome" into brackets to use it as a reference "RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (welcome)"

Comment: ok,can i reference to a regex such as `(/regex/)` with %1?

Comment: yes, you can - but as far as i know you don't need the slashes.

Comment: but if i try `(welcome$)` , so that the query must end with welcome, it accept also `?welcomeword` and apply the rule. How can I solve this last problem,please?

Comment: Put the $ outside the brackets - that works for me: (welcome)$